# Show context menu only when modifier key held

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to make the browsers context menu only appear when holding a certain key (left ctrl) and right clicking. To do so, I need to keep track of which keys are held down.

I have a semi-working solution, however when the context menu is open, the `keyup` event doesnt fire. This means that I cant capture the user removing their finger off the ctrl button while the context menu is open, which means the app continues thinking the key is pressed when it's not.

```
function App() {
  const keys = useRef<Set<string>>(new Set());

  useEffect(() => {
    function onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
      keys.current.add(e.code);
    }
    function onKeyUp(e: KeyboardEvent) {
      keys.current.delete(e.code);
    }
    function onContextMenu(e: MouseEvent) {
      const has = keys.current.has("ControlLeft");
      if (!has) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);
    window.addEventListener("contextmenu", onContextMenu);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);
      window.removeEventListener("contextmenu", onContextMenu);
    };
  });

  return <div className="App" />;
}
```

A possible solution is to simply remove `ControlLeft` from the set of pressed keys *before* returning from the `onContextMenu` handler, e.g.

```
function onContextMenu(e: MouseEvent) {
  const has = keys.current.has("ControlLeft");
  if (!has) {
    // ctrl not pressed so dont show menu 
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    // ctrl pressed, allow menu to show but 
    // assume ctrl is no longer pressed after showing the menu
    keys.current.delete("ControlLeft");
  }
}
```

However this has two problems:

- Assuming the user is no longer pressing the key
- Doesnt work with react 18 strict mode due to the event firing twice

#### Edit

After retrying this again today, it does seem to work in React 18. I'm not sure whether the double-firing events was another issue or is intermittent with React 18.